# Docker not reporting memory usage correctly?

Tags: linux, memory, docker, centos7, rhel7

Through some longevity testing with docker (docker 1.5 and 1.6 with no memory limit) on (centos 7 / rhel 7) and observing the systemd-cgtop stats for the running containers, I noticed what appeared to be very high memory use. Typically the particular application running in a non-containerized state only utilizes around 200-300Meg of memory. Over a 3 day period I ended up seeing systemd-cgtop reporting that my container was up to 13G of memory used. While I am not an expert Linux admin by any means, I started digging in to this which pointed me to the following articles:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34795/correctly-determining-memory-usage-in-linux

http://corlewsolutions.com/articles/article-6-understanding-the-free-command-in-ubuntu-and-linux

So basically what I am understanding is to determine the actual free memory within the system unit would be to look at the -/+ buffers/cache: within "free -m" and not the top line, as I also noticed that the top line within "free -m" would constantly increase with memory used and constantly show a decreased amount of free memory just like what I am observing with my container through systemd-cgtop. If I observe the -/+ buffers/cache: line I will see the actual stable amounts of memory being used / free. Also, if I observe the actual process within top on the host, I can see the process itself is only ever using less then 1% of memory (0.8% of 32G).

I am a bit confused as to whats going on here. If I set a memory limit of 500-1000M for a container (I believe it would turn out to be twice as much due to the swap) would my process eventually stop when I reach my memory limit, even though the process itself is not using anywhere near that much memory? If anybody out there has any feedback on the former, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used docker in CentOS 7 for a while, and got the same confused by these. Checking the github issues link, it looks like `docker stats` in this release is kind of mislead.

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10824

so I just ignored memory usage getting from `docker stats`.

Answer (score 0):

A year since you asked, but adding an answer here for anyone else interested. If you set a memory limit, I think it would not be killed unless it fails to reclaim unused memory. the cgroups metrics and consequently docker stats shows page cache+RES. You could look at the cgroups [detailed](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/runmetrics/) metrics to see the [breakup](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt) 
I had a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41687155/6919159) and when I tested with a memory limit, I saw that the container is not killed. Rather the memory is reclaimed and reused.